# 100% Jest code coverage with unknown errors in a try-catch and throw structure

Tags: javascript, jestjs, code-coverage

If I execute `$ npx jest --coverage` on my project I'm getting 100% code coverage in all my files and I'm very proud of that. However, because of the pattern defined below, files that uses it won't show 100% coverage. The structure pattern is the next:

```js
try {
  thirdPartyCode(myData); // It is documented that ErrorType1 and ErrorType2 might be triggered.
} catch(e) {
  if(e instanceof ErrorType1) return e;
  if(e instanceof ErrorType2) return e;
  throw e; // To avoid silent triggered unknown errors, they're re-thrown. 
}
```

The line that reduces coverage is the `throw e;`.

How can I avoid this issue and get a 100% coverage and avoid silent errors?

Comment: Is this the same with the if ... elseif ... else syntax ?

Comment: Code coverage is a tool not a rule. It exists to help you design _fewer_ and _better_ tests. If it is used as a metric to keep your manager happy, people will start gaming the system and start writing tests for _less-than-likely_ scenarios. If you own the function (which I supposed you don't in this case), you can use tools like [`testdouble.js`](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js) which allows you to define the outcome of a function given a set of input.